# How to get year from a file, column containing datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

this is what I am doing to get year(1880) from year column(year: 01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM),

```
    import pandas
    from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

    data = pandas.read_csv('Landings.csv')
    a=data['year']
    years = **datetime.datetime.a**
    print years
```

I think the hightlited line  is creating probnem anyone correct me, how to get year[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `data["year"]` returns a `Series` of strings, rather than a string, hence you need to `apply`/`map` a parser to to.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = pd.read_csv("Landings.csv")
a=data["year"]
years = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in a]
```

Alternatively. A more `pandas`-esque solution (basically, use the `pandas.Series.apply`method instead of the list generator). This will leave you in the realm of `numpy`/`pandas`

```
years = data["year"].apply(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year)
```

Example

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: data = pd.DataFrame({"year": ["01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM"]})

In [4]: data
Out[4]: 
                     year
0  01/01/1880 12:00:00 AM

In [5]: a = data["year"]

In [6]: [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in a]
Out[6]: [1880]
```

Comment: I am Getting an error:--- years = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year for date in a]                                              TypeError: must be string, not float

Comment: @HariRama it means your `data['year']` contains floats, not strings as you expect. Provide a snippet of your data in the question.

Comment: @HariRama I guess pandas's csv-reader tries to interpret that column as float. You can manually specify to parse that column as string.

Comment: ok, let me do as you suggested, but the edited one not working.         "*years = data["year"].apply(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year*"

Comment: @HariRama you forgot the closing parentheses

Comment: Sorry@ Eli Korvigo,  I missed it in comment. This is what I am Doing ::-                                                                                                     data = pd.read_csv('Meteorite_Landings.csv')
years = data["year"].apply(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year)
print years

Comment: File "C:/Users/shiv/Desktop/getdate.py", line 5, in <module>years= data["year"].apply(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year)File "C:\Python2lib\sitepackages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2169, in applymapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1059, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62578)File "C:/Users/shiv/Desktop/getdate.py", line 5, in <lambda>years = data["year"].apply(lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year)
TypeError: must be string, not float

Comment: @HariRama As I've already mentioned, the error is not related to my code. Pandas's csv parser interprets your "year" column as floats. You should try to specify the data tupe manually. Or your can give me a piece of your data (first 5 lines as text, not a screenshot) so I could do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'a' is a string, it is not a callable function in the datetime module. The following code should work.

```
import pandas
from datetime import date, datetime, strptime, timedelta

data = pandas.read_csv('Landings.csv')
a=data['year']
years = datetime.strptime(a, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p').year
print years
```

Comment: I think Eli's answer is the correct one. I wasn't thinking that years is a list, not a string.